# Enable all warnings in Python, after they were disabled by an imported module

Tags: python, warnings

I have the following snippet:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([False, True])
print(a[b])
```

It triggers a `VisibleDeprecationWarning` as expected.

Now when I import a certain module, that warning is no longer shown:

```
import questionable_module
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([False, True])
print(a[b])
```

How do I need to modify my code in order to re-enable all warnings? I neither want nor can change the `questionable_module`. I would prefer to do it in the code instead of command line arguments, if possible.

The `questionable_module` is `Glumpy` but I'm looking for a solution that works independently of what other modules do.

Comment: What is this "questionable_module" and how does it affect the "warnings" settings?

Comment: @MSeifert: It's Glumpy, a rather large module for OpenGL. I don't understand what it does to warning, but anyway, I'm looking for a solution that works independently of what other modules do.

Comment: There are lots of dials one can turn with `warnings`. The Python warning system is really complicated and to appropriatly answer the question it's necessary to find out **how** they altered (or should I say ... messed) with the warnings. It was actually possible to search their source code and I think I've found the offender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked and it seems for `glumpy` they use [`logging.captureWarnings`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) to catch the warnings:

> ```
> import warnings
> import logging
> logging.captureWarnings(True)
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/blob/371d65a229cb7dfa7cf73ec0b428449e5e9ba76e/glumpy/ext/ffmpeg_reader.py#L37)

I'm not sure if they intended to log all warnings but you can disable it with

```
import logging
logging.captureWarnings(False)
```

---

#### Other possibilities (that don't apply in this case) but could be helpful in the future:

In general it could also be that they adjusted the [`warnings.simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) you could enable it again like this:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("always", VisibleDeprecationWarning)
```

or reset it to the default with [`warnings.resetwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.resetwarnings).

If it's actually a NumPy floating point warning you, then you need to use [`numpy.seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='warn')
```

But it could also be that the `questionable_module` **really** replaces or patches the functions in a way that they actually **never** get to the point where the warning is raised. In that case you probably can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import warnings
import questionable_module
warnings.resetwarnings() # Reset the warnings filter. This discards the effect of all previous calls to filterwarnings(), including that of the -W command line options and calls to simplefilter().
warnings.simplefilter('default')
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([False, True])
print(a[b])
```